# Spider chart plugin for Flot, does it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

I'm trying to write a spider chart using flot, HTML, jQuery and JavaScript but the plugin isn't working for me. I have taken the exact code from the page source of the example to test it on my own computer but it doesn't work.

I've changed the filepath at the top but it still isn't working, is there a problem with the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the correct answer, but that's a thirdparty plugin, and isn't guaranteed to be kept up-to-date with Flot.  So if you're using the latest version of Flot you may want to try an older one, like 0.7.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the JUMlib.js file too:

http://jumflot.jumware.com/Experimental/jquery.flot.JUMlib.js

along with:

http://jumflot.jumware.com/Experimental/jquery.flot.spider.js

The only other thing that caught me out is that you must have:

```
series: {
    spider:{
        active: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle at the bottom of their example doesn't appear to work either? http://jumflot.jumware.com/examples/Experimental/Spider.html